# Svelte-ChartJS chart binding

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-plugin-zoom, svelte-chartjs

I am trying to use [svelte-chartjs](https://github.com/SauravKanchan/svelte-chartjs/blob/master/sandboxes/line/components/Chart.svelte) with [chartjs-plugin-zoom](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/latest/guide/developers.html). In order to programmatically adjust zoom. In order to do this you have to bind onto the element. This can be illustrated in the [React-ChartJS-2](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-nzd04h) - see buttons below.

Is there a prop in svelte-chartjs to make that binding?

Something like:

```
<Line chartRef={myrefvar} {options} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`bind:property`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-component-directives-bind-property) [(tutorial)](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-bindings) to get the chart reference  » [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/a7cd096384cf48b1a77a91f26207159d?version=3.55.1)

```
<script>
    ...

    let chartRef

    const onZoomPluse = () => {
        chartRef.zoom(1.1);
    };
</script>

<Line bind:chart={chartRef} options={options} data={data} />

<button on:click={onZoomPluse}>zoom +10%</button>
```